# Should i use MongoTemplate or DBCollection when query data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

[Java Spring] At the moment, I'm using MongoTemplate to query data

1. MongoTemplate --> return List

   mongoTemplate.find(query, entity)
2. DbCollection --> return DbCursor

   dbCollection.find()

Then what should i use to best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your application is a spring application i would suggest to stick with mongotemplate as it is springframework provided class and can go along well with other spring features.
whereas DBcollection is a class from mongo API for java and there might be some cases where you have to play around to get your stuff done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can explain or show me article about things above. And important is the difference (performance or else) between them

Comment: i can give you some links with examples...but the point that you need to understand is DBcollection is like jdbc you can use it as plain thing without any framework where as mongotemplate is like jdbctemplate which is a framework implementation of jdbc. so mongotemplate is nothing more than a framework specific implementation of dbcollection.

Comment: with mongotemplate you don't need to worry about managing and suffering from infrastructure/plumbing code and purely worry about data and its mapping to objects because framework will do it for you. Spring utilizes Template pattern to hide all low level details while giving you extension hooks to extend and work with dbcollection